# Firebase doc does not accept the path specified using the received useRouter id in next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-typescript

I want to get data about the project, but I can’t do it dynamically, it just doesn’t accept the id.

```
const router = useRouter();
const {projectID} = router.query;
const getProject = doc(firestore, `projects/${projectID}`);
```

If specified statically and this works:

```
const getProject = doc(firestore, `projects/CEtVpthX9zMqUsyYSjEQ`);,
```

But when I tried to check string like

```
console.log(`projects/${projectID}` === `project/CEtVpthX9zMqUsyYSjEQ`)
```

and it says this equal.
Also I tried using variables like

```
const path = `projects/${projectID}`;
const getProject = doc(firestore, path);
```

and

```
const path = `${projectID}`;
const getProject = doc(firestore, 'projects/' + path);
```

and its doesn't work.

I'm also tried to get id from url using useParams from react-router-dom, but it also doesnt work, because I couldnt  get id.

Im try to explain:

```
const router = useRouter();
const {projectID} = router.query;
const path = `projects/${projectID}`;
const staticPath = `projects/CEtVpthX9zMqUsyYSjEQ`
console.log(path);
console.log(staticPath);
console.log(path===staticPath);
const getProject = doc(firestore, path);
```

its output that: telegra.ph/Output-with-dynamic-path-03-27
and if I use

```
const getProject = doc(firestore, staticPath);
```

its outputs that: telegra.ph/Output-with-static-path-03-27

Page full code:

```
function Projects(): JSX.Element {
    const router = useRouter();
    const {projectID} = router.query;
    const path = `${projectID}`;
    const getProject = doc(firestore, `projects/${projectID}`);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [project, setProject] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProjectData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(getProject);
            if (docSnap.exists()){
                const newProjectObj = {
                    id: docSnap.id,
                    ...docSnap.data()
                };
                setProject(newProjectObj);
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.log(docSnap.data());
            } else{
                console.log("Нет данных")
            }
        }
        fetchProjectData();
        return 
    }, []);
    if(isLoading) return <div>Загрузка...</div>;
    return (
        <>
        <div className={cn(styles.heading, styles.headBlock)}>
            {Object.keys(project) && Object.keys(project).length ?
                <div>
                  <ProjectDetailed project={project}/>
                  <CallBackBlock></CallBackBlock>
                </div>
            :null}
            
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default withLayout(Projects);
```

Comment: If it's true that `\`projects/${projectID}\` === \`project/CEtVpthX9zMqUsyYSjEQ\``  then I don't see how this has anything to do with Firestore at all.  In the end, it's just going to receive the exact same string regardless of how you built it.  Since we can't see how you are adding this debug logging in relation to you call to Firestore, I don't think there's anything we can do to help.  Please edit the question to show just once code block with all your logging, as well as the output from your logging.

Comment: Also we can't see how you are actually performing the query with `getProduct`, nor can we see the data in the collection, so we don't if you're doing that correctly either.

Comment: Im added a full page code to question.